# Laravel query builder array change

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Good day all !!

I have laravel query builder array.
I want to set custom value to it.

e.g.

```
$data = DB::table("table_name")->get();

$data->layout = 'something';
OR 
$data['layout'] = 'something';
```

Can we do this ?
IF yes, then how, because right now I am getting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get record from a collection or an array first and then add custom data:

```
$data = DB::table("table_name")->get();
$data[0]->layout = 'something';
```

Or:

```
$data = DB::table("table_name")->first();
$data->layout = 'something';
```

Answer (score 0):

**For array access**:

```
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = DB::table("table_name")->get();
$data[0]['layout'] = 'something';
```

OR

```
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = DB::table("table_name")->first();
$data['layout'] = 'something';
```

**For object access:**

```
$data = DB::table("table_name")->get();
$data[0]->layout = 'something';
```

OR

```
$data = DB::table("table_name")->first();
$data->layout = 'something';
```